# How to migrate from Material design 2 to 3 (MDC 1.4.0 to MDC 1.5.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, migration, material-design, material-design-3

I've been trying to do everything according to [Migrating to Material Design 3](https://material.io/blog/migrating-material-3), but nothing worked.

Android Studio can't see `Theme.Material3`.

My current project uses `Theme.MaterialComponents`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I had to do was to replace dependencies in the `gradle` folder:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-beta01'
```

I found the solution in [Getting started with Material Components for Android - Migration guidance](https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/getting-started)